# Mostrar mensaje correspondiente PHP

Tags: php, html5, aplicación-web, web

Estoy haciendo una web en la universidad y es la primera vez que utilizo `php`, así que desconozco bastante del lenguaje y de desarrollo web en general.

El problema que tengo es el siguiente:

Tengo un `array` de objetos que se llama `$recibidos` donde he guardado todos los mensajes que ha recibido un usuario (cada mensaje es un objeto) y los muestro en una tabla tal que así:

```
<tbody>
     <?php 
         for($i = 0; $i < count($recibidos); $i++) {
             echo '
                 <tr>
                     <td><a onclick="leer()">'.$recibidos[$i]->getAsunto().'</a></td>
                     <td>'.$recibidos[$i]->getEmisor().'</td>
                     <td>'.$recibidos[$i]->getFecha().'</td>
                 </tr>
             ';
         }
     ?>
</tbody>
```

La función `leer()` solo oculta la tabla y muestra el `div` para leer el mensaje (Todo se muestra en la misma página).

Este es el resultado:[image: ejemplo1]

Hasta aquí todo bien, el problema es que quiero que cuando pulse en el campo asunto del mensaje te muestre el mensaje correspondiente, pero no se como acceder a él.

Si hago algo como esto:

```
<div id="leer">
     <div>
         <label>De: </label> <?php echo $recibidos[$i]->getEmisor();?>
     </div>
 </div>
```

obviamente da igual en que mensaje haga <kbd>click</kbd> porque siempre me va a mostrar el emisor del último mensaje.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que al hacer <kbd>click</kbd> en el primer mensaje lea los campos del primer mensaje? ¿Tengo que crear una variable o función aparte, o hay alguna función de `php` que me permita hacer algo así?

Comment: Yo montaria una llamada ajax con jquery que me devuelva los datos (con el formato HTML) del mensaje correspondiente y luego lo insertaria en el div leer y haria este visible.

Comment: Tu problema es de índices únicamente? A la hora de pintar el `HTML` Sustituye `$recibidos[$i]->getEmisor();` donde `i` sea un índice único, no?

Comment: @Lithorell puedes poner un ejemplo? Entiendo lo que dices pero no se como hacerlo.

Comment: El ejemplo mas parecido que he encontrado es este https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28103491/how-do-i-send-parameter-in-ajax-function-call-in-jquery

Comment: Pues para que guarde el id del mensaje en concreto, puedes hacer el metodo `leer()` lo reciba como parametro lo cual podría ser `"onclick='leer("<?php echo $recibidos[$i]->getEmisor();?>")` algo así @Pablovg y que lo mande desde javascript a mostrar

Answer (score 1):

Podrías hacerlo como ya te había comentado, ya sea simplemente pasando el mensaje y lo que quieras mostrar o todo el objeto, que también es una opción, lo que haces al recibirlo como parametro, y que se lo mandes por la tabla, es que, cada vez que pase colocando los datos en la fila de la tabla, también va a colocar como parametro los datos del mensaje el cual se está llenando en esa fila, entonces, un ejemplo podría ser el siguiente:
`JS`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function leer(emisor, mensaje){
   //Agregando a lo que ya tienes
   var divLeer = document.getElementById("leer");
   var html = "<div><label>De: </label>"+ emisor +"></div>";
   divLeer.innerHTML = html;
   }
</script>
```

Entonces lo que haces, es que lo que haces dentro del `div id="leer"` es ya no ponerlo tú desde el `HTML`, sino, mandárselo desde `javascript` por lo tanto el `HTML` quedaría así

`HTML`

```
<tbody>
     <?php 
         for($i = 0; $i < count($recibidos); $i++) {
             echo '
                 <tr>
                     <td><a onclick="leer($recibidos[$i]->getEmisor(), $recibidos[$i]->getMensaje())">'.$recibidos[$i]->getAsunto().'</a></td>
                     <td>'.$recibidos[$i]->getEmisor().'</td>
                     <td>'.$recibidos[$i]->getFecha().'</td>
                 </tr>
             ';
         }
     ?>
</tbody>
```

```
<div id="leer"> </div>
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos!!

Answer (score 0):

Pues puntualmente eso no lo haces con PHP si no con javascript y css el mensaje puedes tenerlo en div oculto por ejemplo

```
<div class="mensaje" id="identificador-unico-1"> xxxxxx</div>
<div class="mensaje" id="identificador-unico-2"> xxxxxx</div>
```

respecto al enlace debes tener algo como por ejemeplo

```
<a onclick="leer('identificador-unico-1')">
```

cuando el usuario precione sobre el enlace la funcion leer selecciona el div  y lo muestra lo puedes hacer con las funciones de jQuery si no quieres darle mucha vuelta al tema.

las funciones serian hiden y show no es mas o puedes buscar otras con una buena animación.

http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/

Comment: Si pero el array de mensajes no tiene un número definido, un usuario puede tener 0 mensajes o puede tener muchos. Si el usuario tiene 500 mensajes tengo que hacer 500 identificadores únicos :S

Comment: Si ese es el caso tienes que utilizar una petición ajax al servidor para obtener todos  los mensajes o presentar un mensaje donde le indique al usuario que no tiene nada que mostrar.